# Separate REST API and App Server

Tags: node.js, performance, rest, security, web-applications

We want to figure out, is it a good practice to split the REST API and App Server. We code both of them with NodeJs and host it on AWS, also note that we want to connect other clients (Android/iOS) with the API and have separate database server.

Our main questions are:

- it is more secure ?
- better performance ?
- there are special features of the development, which we must consider?
- that is then the REST server is down? do we have to cache the data on the App Server ?
- we also have some simple logic on the client side like "password forget", which server handle this ? (App- or REST server)
- which of them handle the authentication ?

Comment: what do you mean by app server and Rest server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is more secure ?

No. It is not. In fact, it is less secure as the attack surface is larger. And you need to individually authenticate and authorize each services.

> better performance ?

Nope. Function calls with in the same application is much faster than serializing -> network latency(http(s) overhead) -> deserializing -> processing -> serializing -> network latency(http(s) overhead) -> deserializing

> there are special features of the development, which we must consider?

Yes, deployment strategy, service discovery, graceful degradation in case of upstream service unavailability.

> that is then the REST server is down? do we have to cache the data on
>   the App Server?

This depends on the situation, there is no universal answer to this question. Trust me, nobody other than your team/product owner can answer this question. Mostly this decision will be driven by the contract that you establish with your consumers. I would suggest to read about circuit breaking/ graceful degradation/ http response codes for partial response etc

> we also have some simple logic on the client side like "password
>   forget", which server handle this ? (App- or REST server) which of
>   them handle the authentication ?

From this question, I am assuming that you don't have a clear separation for individual responsibilities of each service yet. That begs the question, why split these into 2 **at this point of time**. Why can't all the functionality reside in one application to begin with. As you evolve, as you start feeling the pain of a monolithic application, you can revisit your architecture and break it into small pieces as it deems fit. In my opinion, for smaller applications, monolithic architecture is much more manageable than microservices.

Just one humble suggestion, I wouldn't name one service REST and other App server, that may give an impression that you may be looking this from an incorrect angle.

In my opinion, if I am coming to a point where my monolithic app is not manageable anymore, I would split it based on functionality (look at unrelated entities and take them out as a separate service)

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, your answer clarified our questions and yeah I think your right, that _I looking this from an incorrect angle_ and mistaken something. We are very new in this topic, there are a lot of terms and ways how can you do it. At the end we don't split it.